# How to check EVA data that has errors

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to manipulate data which has information like title, short description and long description all in multi-language.

The short and long description does not follow any rules. I would like to harmonize them in order to be well referenced on search engines and above all to avoid repetitions on my files.
I am using the ‘Translatable behavior extension for Doctrine 2’ bundle
So I use this class:

```
Class Fiche {
#[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')] 
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;
/**
     * Used locale to override Translation listener`s locale
     * this is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property
     */
    #[Gedmo\Locale]
    private $locale;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    #[Gedmo\Translatable]
    private ?string $descriptionCourte = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    #[Gedmo\Translatable]
    private ?string $descriptionLongue = null;
[…]
```

In the ddlfile example [ddlfile](https://dbfiddle.uk/nVQr7q2X), 'url1' to 'url6' represent 6 objects that I need to rebuild.

The short and long description content can be repeated, be absent (one or the other or both) etc…
So I also have to set the shortDescription and longDescription fields of the file table for the lang ‘fr’ otherwise, for the other languages, I have to add them to the ext_translations table (for the translations bundle).

1. I can have short or long descriptions, both or none of the 2 represented [url2/data2, url3/data3, url4, url1/data1]

   2. I need to check that the short description is not equal (removing the last 3 characters as I potentially have '...' at the end) to the long description, represented as [url1/data1]. There are short descriptions totally different from the long description (with or without translation) and those I want to keep
   3. I can have the short description (shortcut) 200 characters same as the long description, but the short description can have translations (lang) that the long description did not represent [url6/data6, url7/data7] .

I therefore want to retrieve the maximum information (short or long description both or none) (example for No. 3 retrieve the long description) but keep the translations of the short description if the description does not have any.

I hope to be precise and especially sorry I use a translator

Comment: What is the expected result of the query you are looking for? Please add this as table in your question.

Comment: Ok I think in a few days time for me to analyze all the possibilities as much as possible (because of data errors). thank you

Comment: I don't understand. Your fiddle shows 22 rows of sample input. So what's the expected outcome for these 22 rows?

Comment: I think the data should be in the question, if the original data is too long it should be reduced to fit in the StackOverflow question.